# Loop through every 'even' line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file with the following structure. For context, a fasta file is simply a text file with a header denoted by '>' and below it is the text. I want to create a for-loop that can iterate through every even line of this fasta file.

The name of the file is chicken_topmotifs.fasta

```
>gene8
ATGAATTATTATACACCTCAAATACTCTCCTCAATCTCTCCAACATTCCCCACCACAATTCTCGGTGACTTTACTACACTTCTACAATCATACACTTCT

>gene12
ATGGTAGATCTCTATTACGATTATCTTTCTTAGATCACATAATTATCACCCCCCCTTATAAATCTACACTTCTACAACCAATTACACTTCTACAAAACA
>gene18
ATGCTTTTACACTTCTACAACTACTTTTAACTCGATACTTCTACAATCTACACATATCACAATAACAAAAACAAAAAGCTACTAATATATATATATACA
>gene21
ATGTCTCAATTTCACCAATCTATAATTTACTACGCCGTACTCTTTATAACCTTACTTTCTTAAATAACATTACACTTCTACATTACATATTTTACATCA
```

```
for sequence in chicken_topmotifs.fasta;
do
    echo $sequence
done
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a blank line before `>gene12`? That will throw off the even-odd` stuff.

Comment: Do you even know how to read every line in the file? Your loop doesn't do it.

Comment: Is the goal of only selecting the even lines to filter out the lines like `>gene18`? If so, it might be more robust to filter out lines starting with `>`.

Comment: no there isn't supposed to be a blank line, the formatting got thrown off when I copy pasted a sample of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do two reads each time through the loop. The first read gets the odd line, the second one gets the even line after it.

```
while read -r gene; do
    read -r sequence
    # do stuff with $sequence
done < chicken_topmotifs.fasta
```

Comment: Alternately `while read -r gene && read -r sequence; do ...`

Comment: it worked thank you so much. I'm new to bash and I'm still wrapping my head around the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- ignore header (`>`) lines
- ignore blank lines

One `bash` idea:

```
while read -r sequence
do
      echo "$sequence"
done < <(grep '^[ATGC]' chicken_topmotifs.fasta)
```

If we don't have to worry about blank lines:

```
while read -r sequence
do
      echo "$sequence"
done < <(grep -v '^>' chicken_topmotifs.fasta)
```

Both of these generate:

```
ATGAATTATTATACACCTCAAATACTCTCCTCAATCTCTCCAACATTCCCCACCACAATTCTCGGTGACTTTACTACACTTCTACAATCATACACTTCT
ATGGTAGATCTCTATTACGATTATCTTTCTTAGATCACATAATTATCACCCCCCCTTATAAATCTACACTTCTACAACCAATTACACTTCTACAAAACA
ATGCTTTTACACTTCTACAACTACTTTTAACTCGATACTTCTACAATCTACACATATCACAATAACAAAAACAAAAAGCTACTAATATATATATATACA
ATGTCTCAATTTCACCAATCTATAATTTACTACGCCGTACTCTTTATAACCTTACTTTCTTAAATAACATTACACTTCTACATTACATATTTTACATCA
```